# jquery loop on Json data using $.each

Tags: jquery, json, foreach

I have the following JSON returned in a variable called data.

**THIS IS THE JSON THAT GETS RETURNED...**

```
[ 
{"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
{"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
{"Id": 10059, "PageName": "jjjjjjj"}
]
```

and I am trying to loop through the collection using $.each but I am running into problems where the alert is showing undefined. I have tried a lot of different syntax but can't seem to figure this out.

The JQuery I am using is

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.PageName);
});
```

Can any one point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**
This is the code I am using to grab the data

```
$.getJSON('/Cms/GetPages/123', null, function(data) {
  fillSelect(data);
});
```

and this is the function that gets called upon call back

```
function fillSelect(data) {
  alert(data);
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.PageName);
  });
}
```

**EDIT 2**
This is slightly confusing me, according to the docs it should work as I have it, but it doesn't. According to fiddler the header shows:-

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

and the JSON is exactly correct above. I am using chrome if this makes any different. Will test in IE and FF....

**EDIT 3**

using $.get produces

```
"[\r\n {\r\n \"Id\": 10041,\r\n \"PageName\": \"01234567890\",\r\n \"MetaId\": 1000,\r\n \"TemplateId\": 2\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Id\": 10001,\r\n \"PageName\": \"about\",\r\n \"MetaId\": 1000,\r\n \"TemplateId\": 1\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Id\": 10056,\r\n \"PageName\": \"fdgdfgdfg\",\r\n \"MetaId\": 1000,\r\n \"TemplateId\": 1\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Id\": 10052,\r\n \"PageName\": \"hjkhjk\",\r\n \"MetaId\": 1000,\r\n \"TemplateId\": 2\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Id\": 10059,\r\n \"PageName\": \"jjjjjjj\",\r\n \"MetaId\": 1000,\r\n \"TemplateId\": 1\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Id\": 10057,\r\n \"PageName\": \"qqqqq\",\r\n \"MetaId\": 1000,\r\n \"TemplateId\": 2\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Id\": 10054,\r\n \"PageName\": \"qwqw\",\r\n \"MetaId\": 1000,\r\n \"TemplateId\": 2\r\n }\r\n]"
```

Comment: It works for me. Make sure data are passed correctly to each method.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

```
var data = [ 
 {"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
 {"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
 {"Id": 10059, "PageName": "jjjjjjj"}
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].PageName);
});

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.PageName);
});
```

these two options work well, unless you have something like:

```
var data.result = [ 
 {"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
 {"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
 {"Id": 10059, "PageName": "jjjjjjj"}
];

$.each(data.result, function(i, item) {
    alert(data.result[i].PageName);
});
```

**EDIT:**

try with this and describes what the result

```
$.get('/Cms/GetPages/123', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

**FOR EDIT 3:**

this corrects the problem, but not the idea to use "eval", you should see how are the response in '/Cms/GetPages/123'.

```
$.get('/Cms/GetPages/123', function(data) {
  $.each(eval(data.replace(/[\r\n]/, "")), function(i, item) {
   alert(item.PageName);
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks like I needed to add `eval(data)`

Comment: in the function "httpData" in jQuery  you can see a called window["eval"] for the json data. you do not need to use eval. this line "$. get ( '/ Cms/GetPages/123'" is to show you that are receiving in "data".

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.3.2&fn=jQuery.ajax
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.3.2&fn=jQuery.httpData

Comment: Have updated answer (see EDIT 3) to show what `$.get` produces

Comment: how are you returning the data in "/ Cms/GetPages/123"?

Comment: Basically its a asp.net mvc project using nhibernate. I am actually using the Newtonsoft.Json dll and overriding the executeResult using the JSonTextWriter and JsonSerializer classes.

Comment: `$.each` works for first index not for second, my json object is `{
"0":{"tech_id":"35","tech_name":"Ajax"},
"1":{"tech_id":"36","tech_name":"Ajax"}
}`

Answer (score 17):

Have you converted your data from string to JavaScript object?

You can do it with `data = eval('(' + string_data + ')');`  or, which is safer, `data = JSON.parse(string_data);` but later will only works in FF 3.5 or if you include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html)

jQuery since 1.4.1 also have function for that, [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

But actually, `$.getJSON()` should give you already parsed json object, so you should just check everything thoroughly, there is little mistake buried somewhere, like you might have forgotten to quote something in json, or one of the brackets is missing.

Comment: Looks like I need to add `fillselect(eval(data));`

Comment: BTW how compatible is `eval`?

Comment: That should be `data = eval('('+string_data+')');`. Also, jQuery has another function `data = jQuery.parseJSON(string_data);`

Comment: There is something not quite right. only `eval(data)` works. Please see my EDIT 2

Comment: I've seen jQuery.parseJSON(string_data) fail in certain instances, where data = eval('('+string_data+')') works just fine.

Answer (score 8):

```
$.each(JSON.parse(result), function(i, item) {
    alert(item.number);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

getJSON will evaluate the data to JSON for you, as long as the correct content-type is used. Make sure that the server is returning the data as application/json.

Comment: according to fiddler the content type is `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`