# SignalR client connection.receive(data) is treated as an array of characters instead of an array of objects

Tags: jquery, json, signalr

I have a SignalR client application that receives a Json serialized list of objects. When I run the following script on the incoming data:

```
connection.received(function (data) {
  $.each(divIds, function (index, id) {
      $.each(data, function (index2, object) {
          updateCell(object.property1);
          updateCell(object.property2);
      });
  });
});
```

alert() tells me that $.each iterates over each character in the incoming data as a string, instead of the data being treated as a list of objects.

The incoming data is:

```
[{"property1":"value1","property2":41.3},{"property1":"value2","property2":43.2},{"property1":"value3","property2":559.1}]
```

The data is created on the server with this:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.None).Trim();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this with the method explained in [jquery loop on Json data using $.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each)

`data = eval(data.replace(/[\r\n]/, ""));`