# Ajax jquery with JsonArray in JSP

Tags: jsp, jquery, arrays

I'm using [JSon-RPC library](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html).

**Servlet:**

I want to put `List<Student>` into `JSonArray` that is the same as `{["name":"AAA","age":"24"]["name":"BBB","age":"12"]}`.
`JsonArray` have a contructor that accepts a `Collection` being the same as parameter.
If result is a `JsonObject` then I'll response to client with method `out.print(instanceJsonObject.toString())`.
Now I don't know how to response `JsonArray` from Server to Client.

```
ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
list.add(new Student("Vu Duc Hoan", "C1010G", "24"));
list.add(new Student("Vu Duc Hoan2", "C1010G2", "242"));

JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
org.json.JSONArray array = new JSONArray(list);
```

**Client:**

Can you tell me how to get data in JsonArray? I'm using `$.getJson`

```
btnJson.click(function(){
    $.getJSON("../DemoAjax/Controller?action=getJson",function(data){
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the servlet code you are looking for, but I think you would need to first convert the `Student` object to the `JSONObject` and then put the `JSONObject`s in `JSONArray`, this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) might help you:

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);

// set the response content-type
response.setContentType("application/json");

PrintWriter out = response.getwriter();

// writing the json-array to the output stream
out.print(jsonArray);
out.flush();
```

In the javascript method the `data` in `function(data)` would contain this json-array and you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each) to get the data in your html page.