# How to use JSON post response? MVC 4 how to access?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following:

```
    $.post('@Url.Action("getName")', postData, function(data) {

    // Can I use my json post data?

    }, 'json');
```

My post response I have

```
   {"Id":1,"Name":"John", "Age": 24}
```

I don't know how to get this post response to show on my page view.

I am using MVC 4 and I have a model in this page already that on dropdown select change triggers this post.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

This should work as simple as this:

```
 $.post('@Url.Action("getName")', postData, function(data) {    
     alert(data.Id);
     console.log(data.Name);
     console.log(data.Age);
    }, 'json');
```

If you need to iterate through json results use [$.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each)

Answer (score 2):

You access the JSON data via property name:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("getName")', postData, function(data) {

    // Can I use my json post data?
    // Yes...
    // Given: data == {"Id":1,"Name":"John", "Age": 24}
    $('#someField').val(data.Name);
    $('#someOtherField').val(data.Age);
    // etc...

}, 'json');
```