# logic to parse json data failing

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json data:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"vm"},{"id":"2","name":"live"}]
```

Here's the code I have to parse:

```
$.getJSON('<%= path to my method%>',function(data) {
    console.log(data);  
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {                      
                   console.log(item[i].id);
           console.log(item[i].name);
    }); //end .each

});//end getJSON.
```

Here are the results in the console:

```
LOG: [{"id":"1","name":"vm"},{"id":"2","name":"live"}] 
LOG: undefined 
LOG: undefined 
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'id': object is null or undefined
```

I found this post:  [jquery loop on Json data using $.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each)

and so I tried to change my code to look like:

```
function(data) {
    console.log(data);  
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
         console.log(data[i].id);
             console.log(data[i].name);
    }); //end .each
```

and this:

```
function(data) {
    console.log(data);  
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item.id);
    console.log(item.name);
    }); //end .each
```

But I keep getting undefined for the ids and names.

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong please?
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

```
function(data) {
       $.parseJSON(data);
       console.log(data);  
       $.each(data, function(i, item) {
             console.log(item.id);
             console.log(item.name);
        }); //end .each
```

Comment: Your last code works for me.

Comment: I bet your `data` contains a string and not a javascript object. Perhaps use `data = $.parseJSON(data);` to cast the string to an object before your `console.log`'s.

Comment: phpisuber01, that doesnt seem to make any difference....  Please check out Edit 1 on my post to see what the code loks like

Comment: working `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/Tks5L/10/

Comment: @markli You didnt put `data = $.parseJSON(data)`, you omitted the `data = `. Prepend it and try again. pXL's fiddle shows it correctly.

Comment: phpisuber01, i had a typo / bug in my attempt to follow your solution. can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC

```
$.each(data,function(i,item)
```

should be

```
$.each(data,function(i)
```

then you can just use this.id and this.name inside the loop.
Even if your solution turns out to be valid, it will still be faster to use mine, because going for data[i] will be slower than just using 'this'

Comment: sorry, that doesn't fix it either. but i will use this instead of data[i]

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.each`, `i` is the index and `item` is the value.  No need to to `item[i]`, like you do in a `for..in`.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {                      
    console.log(item.id);
    console.log(item.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function() {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.name);
});
```

Comment: I think it is a moot point because, as one of the posters recognized, when the OP logs his json object it is coming through as a string. Shouldn't the console display it as [object][object] ?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is coming through as a string instead of a JSON object, therefore you're not able to access its properties.

Cast the string of JSON into an actual object by using `$.parseJSON()`.

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

The above should do the trick.

If your JSON source is potentially unreliable, I would suggest try/catch blocks to prevent invalid JSON from borking your javascript:

```
try {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
} catch(errors) {
    console.log(errors);
}
```

Finally, if you control the source of the JSON, you can set the headers in the response to `application/json` and jQuery should automagically cast the response to a JSON object.

Comment: You mean `application/json` :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah! That too. I believe they are interchangeable.

Comment: They aren't actually.  `application/javascript` and `application/json` are totally different ^_^

Comment: @RocketHazmat Updated answer. You are correct, I must of been thinking about JSON-P. >_> Thanks!