# How to populate dropdownlist with JSON data as ajax response in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my application I have a drop-down list. I want to populate this drop-down list with JSON data from an Ajax response.

Below is the code what I have:

**The JSON data which the server sends:**

```json
{
  "aaData": [
    {
      "value": "login1",
      "text": "kapils"
    },
    {
      "value": "login2",
      "text": "davidn"
    },
    {
      "value": "login3",
      "text": "alanp"
    }
  ]
}
```

**and Below is my Client side code which generates the ajax request:**

**(Using $.ajax() ) :**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
$('#id_trial').click(function() {
    
    alert("entered in trial button code");
        
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"/demo_trial_application/json_source",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.aaData,function(i,data)
            {
             alert(data.value+":"+data.text);
             var div_data="<option value="+data.value+">"+data.text+"</option>";
            alert(div_data);
            $(div_data).appendTo('#ch_user1'); 
            });  
            }
      });
    });
});

</script>

<body>

<div id="div_source1">
    <select id="ch_user1" >
        <option value="select"></option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="id_trial" name="btn_trial" value="Trial Button..">
</body>
```

**OR Using ($.getJSON()) :**

```js
$.getJSON("/demo_trial_application/json_source", function (data) {
    $.each(data.aaData, function (i, data) {
        var div_data = "<option value=" + data.value + ">" + data.text + "</option>";
        alert(div_data);
        $(div_data).appendTo('#ch_user1');

    });
});
```

Now when I clicked on button (#id_trial), the server side code executes successfully and as a result JSON object created But I am not getting that "JSON response" in callback function of Success parameter using jQuery's ajax call.

I also tried with `$.getJSON` function to receive JSON response..but I didn't get JSON data.

So please tell me if there is any mistake in my code, and how to get JSON data using above code and populate drop-down list.

Comment: have you looked in firebug to see if there's clientside json arriving??

Comment: kits@ I have checked your ajax code with php json data, its working fine. Am using jQuery v1.10.2.  I don't think javascript has error.

Comment: check your.each() loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try to change the jquery method variable, it might be causing the problem (i.e., you are using the `data` variable coming from the ajax callback PLUS are then trying to assign it to the `item` object in the jquery method - changed to `obj`):

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"/demo_trial_application/json_source",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.aaData,function(i,obj)
                {
                 alert(obj.value+":"+obj.text);
                 var div_data="<option value="+obj.value+">"+obj.text+"</option>";
                alert(div_data);
                $(div_data).appendTo('#ch_user1'); 
                });  
                }
          });
        });
```

Comment: Jim, In that case I have tried the kits code and it is working fine, the only change is, I have used PHP server side code to generate the json objects.  Is it give much difference in place? can you please guide me on this?

Comment: I highly recommend console.log() over alert().

Answer (score 3):

I use "for"

```
var List;
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/demo_trial_application/json_source",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
    List = data.aaData
        $('#ch_user1').empty();
        $('#ch_user1').append('<option value="">All</option>');
        for (i in List ) {
            $('#ch_user1').append('<option value="' + List[i].value + '">' + List[i].text + '</option>');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Working with Laravel this is my solution:

```
$("#YOUR_DIV").on("change", function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    makeAjaxRequest(selected);
})

function makeAjaxRequest(opts){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url : '{{ action('YOUR_CONTROLLER@YOUR_FUNCTION') }}',
        data: { opts: opts },
        success: function(data) {
            NEW_JS_FUNCTION(data);
        }
    });
}

function NEW_JS_FUNCTION(params) {
    $('#YOUR_DIV').empty();
    $('#YOUR_DIV').append('<option value="">ALL</option>');

    params.forEach(function(entry){
        $('#YOUR_DIV').append('<option value="' + entry.KEY+ '">' + entry.TEXT + '</option>');
    });

}
```

It works. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

We can populate dropdown like below . it's very easy for you all i guess.

```
var options = $("#options");
    $.getJSON("/Country/GetAll/", function(response) {
         $.each(response, function() {
         options.append($("<option />").val(this.Id).text(this.Name));
     });
  });
```

Comment: Nice append one-liner!

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <%--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtGender" />--%>
                                        <select class='form-control DropDown' id="txtGender"></select>
                                    </div>

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AjaxCallGrid.asmx/GetDropDown",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('.DropDown').empty();
                        $('.DropDown').append("<option value='0'>---Select---</option>");
                        $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {
                            $('.DropDown').append($("<option></option>").val(value.iD).html(value.firstName));
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [WebMethod]
        public  List<Students> GetDropDown()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            List<Students> result = new List<Students>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DOS-PC\MARJI;Initial Catalog=examples;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id,firstname from Students ", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            result.Add(new Students
                            {
                                iD = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString()),
                                firstName = dt.Rows[i]["firstname"].ToString()
                            }
                                );
                        }
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try as follows

```
<select id="xxx"></select>

success: function (response) {                   

     for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

           $("#xxx").append("<option value='" + response[i]["id"] + "'>" + response[i]["name"] + "</option>");

     }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can do it:

```
$(".ddEvent").on('change', function(e){
    const selectedEvent                 = $(this).val();
    $("#ddExhibitor").empty();
    $("#ddExhibitor").append("<option value='-1'>-- Choose Exhibitor --</option>");

     $.ajax({
         url: '/dashboard/get-exhibitors/'+selectedEvent,
         type: 'GET',
         success: function success(data) {
         if(data.exhibitors.length > 0){
             data.exhibitors.forEach(exhibitor => {
                  $("#ddExhibitor").append("<option value='" + exhibitor.id + "'>" + exhibitor.exhibitor_name + "</option>");
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function error(err) {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }
                });
            });
```