I am struggling to get prefill data while editing document in php
<?php
session_start();
include '../config.php';

// Check if user is logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Please Login First..!!!');
            window.location.href='index.php';
           </script>");
    exit();
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_associate_master WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$associate = $result->fetch_assoc();
$stmt->close();

include 'intelmark_head.php';
include 'intelmark_sidebar.php';
?>

<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1 class="m-0">Edit Associate</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Edit Associate</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form id="associateForm">
                <div class="card card-default">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Edit Associate</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="associate_id" value="<?php echo $associate['id']; ?>">
                        <div class="mine_box">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- Associate Name -->
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="associate_name">Associate Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="associate_name"
                                            name="associate_name" placeholder="Enter Associate Name"
                                            value="<?php echo $associate['associate_name']; ?>" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- Contact Names in one line -->
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="contact_name1">Contact Name 1</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_name1"
                                            name="contact_name1" placeholder="Enter Contact Name 1"
                                            value="<?php echo $associate['contact_name1']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="contact_name2">Contact Name 2</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_name2"
                                            name="contact_name2" placeholder="Enter Contact Name 2"
                                            value="<?php echo $associate['contact_name2']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="contact_name3">Contact Name 3</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_name3"
                                            name="contact_name3" placeholder="Enter Contact Name 3"
                                            value="<?php echo $associate['contact_name3']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="addressContainer">
                            <div class="address_mine_box" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <div class="address-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <!-- Address -->
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="address1_line1">Address</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1_line1"
                                                    name="address_line1[]" placeholder="Enter Address Line 1"
                                                    value="<?php echo $associate['address1_line1']; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="address1_line2">Address Line 2</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1_line2"
                                                    name="address_line2[]" placeholder="Enter Address Line 2"
                                                    value="<?php echo $associate['address1_line2']; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <!-- Country, State, City -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="address1_country">Country</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" id="address1_country" name="country[]">
                                                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                                                    <!-- Add PHP code to fetch and display countries -->
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="address1_state">State</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" id="address1_state" name="state[]">
                                                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                                                    <!-- Add PHP code to fetch and display states based on country -->
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="address1_city">City</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" id="address1_city" name="city[]">
                                                    <option value="">Select City</option>
                                                    <!-- Add PHP code to fetch and display cities based on state -->
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <!-- Pincode -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="address1_pincode">Pincode</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1_pincode"
                                                    name="pincode[]" placeholder="Enter Pincode"
                                                    value="<?php echo $associate['address1_pincode']; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>&nbsp;</label><br>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary add-address-btn">Add Address</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-address-btn" style="display: none;">Remove Address</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Add more addresses as needed, similarly -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="mine_box">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- Phone -->
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="phone1">Phone</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone1" name="phone1"
                                            placeholder="Enter Phone" value="<?php echo $associate['phone_number1']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="phone2">Phone</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone2" name="phone2"
                                            placeholder="Enter Phone" value="<?php echo $associate['phone_number2']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="phone3">Phone</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone3" name="phone3"
                                            placeholder="Enter Phone" value="<?php echo $associate['phone_number3']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Email -->
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email1">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" name="email1"
                                            placeholder="Enter Email" value="<?php echo $associate['email1']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email2">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email2" name="email2"
                                            placeholder="Enter Email" value="<?php echo $associate['email2']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email3">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email3" name="email3"
                                            placeholder="Enter Email" value="<?php echo $associate['email3']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Website -->
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="website">Website</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website" name="website"
                                            placeholder="Enter Website" value="<?php echo $associate['website']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Remark -->
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="remark">Remark</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="remark" name="remark"
                                        placeholder="Enter Remark"><?php echo $associate['remarks']; ?></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<?php include 'intelmark_footer.php'; ?>
<style>
.mine_box {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.address-group {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.address_mine_box {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.remove-address-btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fetch countries and pre-select values
    $.ajax({
        url: 'city_state_country_fetch.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { type: 'countries' },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.error) {
                console.error("Error fetching countries: " + response.error);
                return;
            }

            var countries = response;
            var options = "<option value=''>Select Country</option>";
            for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
                options += "<option value='" + countries[i].id + "'>" + countries[i].country_name + "</option>";
            }
            $("[name='country[]']").html(options);

            // Pre-select country values
            var countryIds = [<?php echo $associate['address1_country_id']; ?>, <?php echo $associate['address2_country_id']; ?>, <?php echo $associate['address3_country_id']; ?>];
            $("[name='country[]']").each(function(index) {
                if (countryIds[index]) {
                    $(this).val(countryIds[index]).change();
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error("Error fetching countries: ", error);
        }
    });

    // Fetch states based on selected country and pre-select values
    $(document).on('change', '[name="country[]"]', function() {
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        var $stateSelect = $(this).closest('.address-group').find('[name="state[]"]');
        var $citySelect = $(this).closest('.address-group').find('[name="city[]"]');
        $citySelect.html("<option value=''>Select City</option>"); // Reset city dropdown

        $.ajax({
            url: 'city_state_country_fetch.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { type: 'states', country_id: countryId },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    console.error("Error fetching states: " + response.error);
                    return;
                }

                var states = response;
                var options = "<option value=''>Select State</option>";
                for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
                    options += "<option value='" + states[i].id + "'>" + states[i].state_name + "</option>";
                }
                $stateSelect.html(options);

                // Pre-select state values
                var stateIds = [<?php echo $associate['address1_state_id']; ?>, <?php echo $associate['address2_state_id']; ?>, <?php echo $associate['address3_state_id']; ?>];
                var stateId = stateIds[$("[name='country[]']").index(this)];
                if (stateId) {
                    $stateSelect.val(stateId).change();
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("Error fetching states: ", error);
            }
        });
    });

    // Fetch cities based on selected state and pre-select values
    $(document).on('change', '[name="state[]"]', function() {
        var stateId = $(this).val();
        var $citySelect = $(this).closest('.address-group').find('[name="city[]"]');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'city_state_country_fetch.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { type: 'cities', state_id: stateId },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    console.error("Error fetching cities: " + response.error);
                    return;
                }

                var cities = response;
                var options = "<option value=''>Select City</option>";
                for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                    options += "<option value='" + cities[i].id + "'>" + cities[i].city_name + "</option>";
                }
                $citySelect.html(options);

                // Pre-select city values
                var cityIds = [<?php echo $associate['address1_city_id']; ?>, <?php echo $associate['address2_city_id']; ?>, <?php echo $associate['address3_city_id']; ?>];
                var cityId = cityIds[$("[name='state[]']").index(this)];
                if (cityId) {
                    $citySelect.val(cityId);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("Error fetching cities: ", error);
            }
        });
    });

    // Add more address fields
    $(document).on('click', '.add-address-btn', function() {
        if ($(".address-group").length < 3) {
            var addressGroup = $(".address_mine_box:first").clone();
            addressGroup.find("input").val("");
            addressGroup.find("select").val("");
            addressGroup.find(".add-address-btn").hide();
            addressGroup.find(".remove-address-btn").show();
            $("#addressContainer").append(addressGroup);
        } else {
            alert("You can only add up to 3 addresses.");
        }
    });

    // Remove address fields
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-address-btn', function() {
        $(this).closest('.address_mine_box').remove();
    });

    // Handle form submission
    $("#associateForm").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'intelmark_associate_master_action.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(response) {
                alert('Associate updated successfully');
                window.location.href = 'intelmark_associate_master.php';
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>

associate_edit.php

<?php
include '../config.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$type = $_GET['type'];
$data = [];

try {
    if ($type == 'countries') {
        $query = "SELECT id, country_name AS name FROM tbl_countries_master";
    } elseif ($type == 'states' && isset($_GET['country_id'])) {
        $country_id = intval($_GET['country_id']);  // Ensure it's an integer
        $query = "SELECT id, state_name AS name FROM tbl_states_master WHERE country_id = $country_id";
    } elseif ($type == 'cities' && isset($_GET['state_id'])) {
        $state_id = intval($_GET['state_id']);  // Ensure it's an integer
        $query = "SELECT id, city_name AS name FROM tbl_cities_master WHERE state_id = $state_id";
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Invalid request');
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception('Database query error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Log the error message to a file or any other logging mechanism
    error_log($e->getMessage());

    // Send a JSON response with the error message
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
?>

I have an associate database with country_id, state_id, and city_id fields. When I try to edit a record, all data is prefilled correctly, but the dropdown options for country, state, and city are not automatically selected based on the prefilled data. How can I ensure that these dropdowns show the selected values corresponding to the prefilled data when editing a record?

Are you struggling with the PHP part or the MySQL part?

Also, please keep in mind that you should never use string concatenation for SQL queries. These queries are widely open for SQL injection - have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

How are the 2 blocks of code related? Why didn't you use prepared statements everywhere?

In the above you have many reliance's upon the variable $associate but no sanity checking to see if it is populated nor to test that there is a GET variable/parameter id set initially. Looking through the code is it within the Javascript change handlers that you are facing the issue (ie: set selected record equal to the matching Id) or once the form has been submitted the dropdowns show default please select...?

@NicoHaase To be fair, they used intval() on the parameter, so SQL injection should not be possible.

Are you asking how to add the SELECTED option to the selected <OPTION when you're filling it in with the AJAX response? How is it supposed to know which city should be selected before the user has chosen it?

There is so much code here, it is hard to tell what you are having trouble with.  Populating <select> options from DB on page load? Search for "php select selected option mysql" : https://stackoverflow.com/q/18733545/6089612  Populating <select> options from DB via AJAX calls after page load?  Search for "populate dropdown AJAX php": https://stackoverflow.com/q/19725203/6089612 Populating a 2nd <select> depending on selection from 1st? Search for "populate second dropdown from first AJAX php": https://stackoverflow.com/q/8749326/6089612

Populating dependent country, state and city <select>s? Search for "country state city select php mysql ajax": https://stackoverflow.com/q/24579361/6089612
Step 1 when you have a problem is to think about whether anyone else has had the same problem before you.  If you're using PHP, the answer is almost always "YES"!  Then all you have to do is search.  The examples I gave might not be the best, there are hundreds or thousands of others here, keep reading until you find one that suits.
