# $each() function not displaying any data brought by the JSON object from the servlet using ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I want to display the book name retrieved from database in the jsp page. Everything is working fine, but when the `ajax` success is to be executed the `each` function is doing the problem. It does not display anything. I checked everything behind and after it, all are working well even the data is retrieved and passed back to the `ajax` as `JSON object` but while `iterating` something is going wrong. If in place of each function of `jquery` i write any other alert function or simple text to display, it is working but not the each function. Where is the problem? Plz help me. Below is the code of my `servlet` and `jsp` page.

**EbookSearchResult.java**

```
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String search=request.getParameter("searchText");
            String pattern="%"+search+"%";
            ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
            try{
                Connectivity obj=new Connectivity();
                obj.connect();
                Statement stmt;
                ResultSet rs;
                stmt=obj.con.createStatement();
                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select bookTitle from ebooks where bookTitle LIKE '"+pattern+"'");
                if (!rs.next()) 
                {                
                    return;
                }          
                while(rs.next()){
                    String str=rs.getString("bookTitle");
                    result.add(str);                    
                }
                String json = new Gson().toJson(result);    
                out.write(json);                        
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                out.println(e.toString());
            }
```

**search.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#SearchButton").click(function()
{
var searchText = $("#search").val();
if(searchText.length > 3)
{
$("#searchResult").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>Checking availability...");
$.ajax({
    // the URL for the request
    url: "EbookSearchResult.do",

    // the data to send (will be converted to a query string)
    data: {
        searchText: searchText
    },

    // whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "POST",

    // the type of data we expect back
    dataType : "json",

    // code to run if the request succeeds;
    // the response is passed to the function
    success: function(json) {        
        $.each(json, function(index,value) {               
            $("#searchResult").append(value);      
                    });
    },

    // code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
    // status codes are passed to the function
    error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        $("#searchResult").html("No Search Results found...");
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
    }
});
}

else
{
$("#searchResult").html("Search Text should be atleast 4 character");
}

});
});

</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Comment: I want the problem that is going on inside my code..

Comment: Give me the output of a JSON when you use the alert in the success function

Comment: if i write alert("Ok") in the success function it happily displays ok but if i write alert("Ok"+json) inside success function to test if any value is printed, it again displays "Ok" but no json data. I want the json data to be displayed anyhow.