# How to print data that gets returned from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I am trying to append data that gets returned from a ajax call.  I have the ajax call working correctly.  However the data returned is one giant character array.  I am using grails MVC, and the value I am returning is a ArrayList.  I want to be able to run a for loop that will go through the items.  But in order to do that I want to know if there is a way to convert 'data' into an array.  The output is shown below.

```
function getAllActivitiItems() {
    console.log ("Starting function");
    $.ajax({
        url: '${g.createLink(controller: 'Activiti', action: 'getAllActivitiQueue')}',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Made it! "+data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

AJAX return data value:

```
[
  ['userId':'FP301', 'taskId':'1', 'storeKey':'001E0', 'callKey':'12634'], 
  ['userId':'TS206', 'taskId':'2', 'storeKey':'00IAC', 'callKey':'12758'], 
  ['userId':'SN304', 'taskId':'3', 'storeKey':'00IAC', 'callKey':'09843']
]
```

Comment: this link could you help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each) or you can use JSON.parse(data)

Comment: Link didn't help, I am returning a List containing a map however the data in ajax success thinks its a character array.  I am trying to print the data, but can't figure out why its returning it as a character array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to have an array of objects? If so, you may need to alter your server's getAllActivitiQueue method to return the data like this:

```
[
    {'userId':'FP301', 'taskId':'1', 'storeKey':'001E0', 'callKey':'12634'}, 
    {'userId':'TS206', 'taskId':'2', 'storeKey':'00IAC', 'callKey':'12758'}, 
    {'userId':'SN304', 'taskId':'3', 'storeKey':'00IAC', 'callKey':'09843'}
]
```

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s3441gw/)

Alternately, you could try using [JSON.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: I am sending a array list that contains a map.  I define List lists = new ArrayList(), then have a each statement (groovy) that adds items to a map.  Once the each statement is completed I then add it too lists, and return.

Comment: I'm calling AJAX call in index.gsp, which calls my controller.  The only way now I can print out my variables when they return is by characters. Ex. Data[0] would print [, and so forth.