# Get array of property values from array of objects with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get from here:

```
example = [{
  name: "someone1",
  city: "somewhere1",
  state: "someplace1"
},{
  name: "someone2",
  city: "somewhere2",
  state: "someplace2"
}]
```

to here:

```
example.name = [ "someone1", "someone2" ]
```

In as little a code as possible. Obviously I could just loop it and build the array but I need to do this a large number of times on a variety of objects. I could write a function to do it but it would be difficult to make the function general enough for my application.

Is there a shortcut for this in jQuery?

Comment: You have to use jquery loop. I hope this will help to you dear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Comment: Native javascript is always going to be faster than jQuery.

Comment: explain a bit more.. you have one object, that is an array of same objects and then..?

Comment: @DeftSoftInformatics No, one doesn't _have to_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can iterate through the object keys and save the `name` in the array using `push`:

```js
example = [{
  name: "someone1",
  city: "somewhere1",
  state: "someplace1"
}, {
  name: "someone2",
  city: "somewhere2",
  state: "someplace2"
}];
var arrNames = [];
//iterate through object keys
Object.keys(example).forEach(function(key) {
  //get the value of name
  var val = example[key]["name"];
  //push the name string in the array
  arrNames.push(val);
});
console.log(arrNames);//prints ["someone1", "someone2"]
```

After @Felix suggestion(with which I agree) there is no need to use `Object.keys`:

```js
example = [{
  name: "someone1",
  city: "somewhere1",
  state: "someplace1"
}, {
  name: "someone2",
  city: "somewhere2",
  state: "someplace2"
}];
var arrNames = [];
//iterate through object keys
example.forEach(function(item) {
  //get the value of name
  var val = item.name
  //push the name string in the array
  arrNames.push(val);
});
console.log(arrNames); //prints ["someone1", "someone2"]
```

**References**

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Just made a generic function of this taking the object name and key names and it works flawlessly. Great answer, thank you!

Comment: `Object.keys(example).forEach(function(key) {` is a very strange way to iterate over an array. Why not simply `example.forEach(function(item) { ... })`?

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling for the feedback. You are right. I will update my answer later.

Comment: How to get this to create an array of values like `["someone1", "somewhere1","someplace1"],[...]` and so on?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function from jQuery :

```
var value = $.map(example, function () {
    return this.name;
});
```

This will return an array of the items.

Comment: This answer works but the one below was accepted because it can do all the property names I need at the same time. +1

Comment: adding parameter to the function worked for me: function (v) { return v.name; }

Answer (score 8):

I made a quick test for you here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascriptlvjsklvjsfklsfklsdjfk

It consists of three solutions:

A basic for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
    array.push(example[i].name);
}
```

A jQuery $.each()

```
$.each(example, function(i, item) {
    array.push(example[i].name);
});
```

And one answer posted to this thread

```
Object.keys(example).forEach(function(key) {
  //get the value of name
  var val = example[key]["name"];
  //push the name string in the array
  array.push(val);
});
```

Here are the results (bigger bar is better) [image]

Basically what you have to keep in mind is that jQuery might have a shortcut which consists of "less code", but in reality it'll have worse performance than if you wrote the code yourself.

Comment: Though forEach is the slowest, I'm not worried about speed and it allows me to do this for all properties I need with one loop (by not having return statements). Thank you for your input; I chose to use forEach as it is the fastest to write for my application.

Comment: This is the best answer to the question tho! You could improve the loop better by checking the length once at the begging and storing it as a local var rather than checking with each loop cycle. i.e.  for (var i = 0, x = example.length; i < x; i++)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it using [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

The line of code is:

```
jinqJs().from(example).select(function(row){return row.name;});
```

```js
var example = [{
  name: "someone1",
  city: "somewhere1",
  state: "someplace1"
},{
  name: "someone2",
  city: "somewhere2",
  state: "someplace2"
}];

var result = jinqJs().from(example).select(function(row){return row.name;});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + '</pre><br><br>';
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fordth/jinqJs/master/jinqjs.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution I can think of:

```
function doThat (myArray) {
  newObject = {};
  myArray.forEach(function (obj, idx) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
      if (!obj[key]) {
        newObject[key] = [];
      }
      newObject[key][idx] = obj[key]; 
    });
  });
  return newObject;
}
```

Comment: I think my solution is more generic since it keeps all the indexes as they were even if one of the objects in the array missed a property