# JS, Loop over Json object list

Tags: javascript, json

This is the results I am getting using `console.log(res)`

```
{d: Array(4)}
d: Array(4)
0: {__type: "Claim_Inbox+SubClaims", Claim_detail: 12, Claim_id: 123, …}
1: {__type: "Claim_Inbox+SubClaims", Claim_detail: 12, Claim_id: 124, …}
2: {__type: "Claim_Inbox+SubClaims", Claim_detail: 12, Claim_id: 125, …}
3: {__type: "Claim_Inbox+SubClaims", Claim_detail: 12, Claim_id: 126,…}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Using the following code I am getting the list of keys:values

```
var counter = 0;
$.each(res.d[counter ], function (key, value) {
   console.log(key + ": " + value);
   counter++;
});
```

how can I read a specific value like `Claim_id` ?
I can use `Switch()` but maybe there is another way

Comment: what do you get with ``res.d.forEach(console.log)``,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) and [Returning only certain properties from an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440403) and [Get array of property values from array of objects with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472655)

Comment: Can you post the raw JSON or the source?

Comment: you cannot use .forEach here

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not an `Object`, it is an `Array`.
Second, depending on what you want, you can use `forEach` to loop over the array and show or assign or do whatever you need with the id OR use `map` to construct a new array with the selected values.

```js
const array = [
  { __type: "Claim_Inbox+SubClaims", Claim_detail: 12, Claim_id: 123 },
  { __type: "Claim_Inbox+SubClaims", Claim_detail: 12, Claim_id: 124 },
  { __type: "Claim_Inbox+SubClaims", Claim_detail: 12, Claim_id: 125 },
  { __type: "Claim_Inbox+SubClaims", Claim_detail: 12, Claim_id: 126 }
];

array.forEach(item => console.log(item['Claim_id']); );

console.log("--------------------");

// Generate a new array copy
const result = array.map(item => item['Claim_id']);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: ``Array`` is an ``Object`` in JS

Comment: @fard yes, they are, but also are functions.... not for that you can loop over a function.... the base of javascript are objects, but they are not the same type of object ;)

Comment: But you can't say that Arrat is not an object, like you do in your first sentence @PrinceHernandez