# Javascript get all values of object

Tags: javascript

I want to get all name from the array of data. Is there any way to do it without using an iterator?

```js
const data = [
    {name: 'Rushabh', age: 22},
    {name: 'Bonny', age: 24}
]

console.log(Object.values(data));
```

Comment: you can always do `data.map(obj => obj.name)` Not sure whether this counts as "using an iterator" or not though. (Any array is technically an iterator.)

Comment: I know but is there any default method to do this thing?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key)

Comment: not to be picky, but the question, whether or not it makes sense, was to **not** use an iterator.  **Why?**  doesn't matter at this point.   Well, without **iterating** you would need to know how many items are in the array before hand, since you, again, are not **iterating**.   Therefore, ```data[0].name``` and ```data[1].name``` are your two choices here.  There have been solutions propsoed, but they **all** use **iteration**.  yes, **map** is an iteration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) and [Get array of property values from array of objects with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472655)

Answer (score 1):

For getting only a single property, you need to map this property directly.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: 'Rushabh', age: 22 }, { name: 'Bonny', age: 24 }],
    result = data.map(({ name }) => name); // get only name

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const data = [
    {name: 'Rushabh', age: 22},
    {name: 'Bonny', age: 24}
]
const names = data.map(({name}) => name)
console.log(names);
```

the `names` will include the list of names.

Answer (score 0):

Without some kind of iterator you can not do that. You can use `map()` with short hand property.

```js
const data = [
    {name: 'Rushabh', age: 22},
    {name: 'Bonny', age: 24}
]
const name = data.map(({name}) => name);
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map()` and extract the `name` property:

```js
const data = [
    {name: 'Rushabh', age: 22},
    {name: 'Bonny', age: 24}
]

console.log(data.map(x => x.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery, do this:

```
const data = [
    {name: 'Rushabh', age: 22},
    {name: 'Bonny', age: 24}
] 
var names = $.map( data, function(item, key) { return item.name; } );
// names : ['Rushabh', 'Bonny']
```