# Jquery Each function,show values in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple JSON array and each function:

```
var result= $.each(response.data, function(k, v) {
                console.log(k); 
            });
```

Now, this work fine, in my console I get all values from JSON. So, is there possibility for values of array show in my HTML page,in some `div`, etc:

```
<div id="my_div"> </div>
```

I try with `append()` and HTML functions, but always get blank `div`.

Thanks

Comment: how did you try append

Comment: Could you please provide a JSFiddle with your code?

Comment: We can't tell what you did wrong if you don't show the code that's having a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html

```
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Js

```
var theData = ['a','b','c','d'];

$.each(theData, function(k, v) {
    $('#my_div').append(v+'<br/>');
});
```

This answer may be useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342433/3052648

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = '';
var result= $.each(response.data, function(k, v) {
    html += "<span>" + k + "</span>"
    console.log(k); 
});
$("#my_div").append(html);
```