# Loop through this array

Tags: php

I make an API request with PHP and the `$data` variable that comes back looks like the following:

```
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "AFC"
}, {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "RFC"
}, {
    "Id": 4,
    "Name": "CFC"
}, {
    "Id": 5,
    "Name": "LFC"
}, {
    "Id": 7,
    "Name": "MUFC"
}]
```

I want to know, how do I use a foreach loop to display a list of the titles?

Comment: for this use `json_decode`

Comment: Many thanks, Sahil - will research into this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Comment: If you get a JSON string (fragment you gave us is not fully valid), use `json_decode`. It would create a stdClass objects structure or assoc array, that's determined by the second function parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the API request, your $data variable contains a JSON string.

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert the string into an array, and the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop construct to iterate over array:

```
$json_object = json_decode($data) ;

echo '<table>' ;
foreach ( $json_object as $child ) {

    echo '<tr>' ;
    echo '<td>' . $child -> Id. '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>' . $child -> Name . '</td>' ;
    echo '</tr>' ;

}
echo '</table>' ;
```

Comment: this worked beautifully. Many thanks for taking the time to put this together. I will keep this in mind for all future json decodes :)

Comment: my pleasure :) i am glad it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
foreach($data as $row){
echo $row["Id"];
echo "<br>";
echo $row["Name"];
}
```