# How to output JSON data with filter applied JavaScript /jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some data on JSON file.

```js
var data = [{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubween",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubween",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubenq",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  }, {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubenr",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  }
];
```

I want to output only `gender: male` with their name on HTML div id='output' using jQuery or JavaScript

Comment: This is an invalid json.

Comment: add your json data properly

Answer (score 0):

Just try it like below.

```js
var data = [{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubween",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubween",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubenq",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  }, {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubenr",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  }
];

data.forEach(function(person) {
  if (person.gender === "male") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += person.name.first + " " + person.name.last + "<br>";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by: [jquery loop on Json data using $.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each)

```js
var obj = [{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubween",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubween",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubenq",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  }, {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubenr",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  }
];

$.each(obj, function(i, item) {
if(obj[i].gender=="male")
  $("#output").append(obj[i].name.first+" - "+obj[i].gender+"<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var data = [{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubween",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubween",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubenq",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  }, {
    "gender": "female",
    "name": {
      "first": "rubenr",
      "last": "dean"
    }
  }
];

$.each(data, function(i){
  if(data[i].gender === 'male')
    $('body').append(`${data[i].name.first} ${data[i].name.last} <br/>`); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you.